# SendInput in a Windows Server

Tags: winapi, windows-server

I would like to simulate mouse moves in a Windows Server (desktop experience). I'm using the Window's function [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) from C#, and the following code is running in the server.

```cs
using Windows.Win32;
using Windows.Win32.UI.Input.KeyboardAndMouse;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1)
{
    var inputs = new INPUT[]
    {
        new()
        {
            type = INPUT_TYPE.INPUT_MOUSE,
            Anonymous = new INPUT._Anonymous_e__Union
            {
                mi = new MOUSEINPUT
                {
                    dx = 0,
                    dy = 0,
                    mouseData = 0,
                    dwFlags = MOUSE_EVENT_FLAGS.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSE_EVENT_FLAGS.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,
                    time = 0,
                    dwExtraInfo = 0,
                },
            },
        }
    };

    if (PInvoke.SendInput(inputs, Marshal.SizeOf<INPUT>()) == 0)
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

It is working perfectly while I keep the remote desktop open, but `SendInput()` returns 0x5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) when I close the session.

I have tried the same in a virtual machine. Whenever I close the virtual machine connection window, `SendInput()` fails.

Any idea how to use `SendInput()` in a Windows Server without keeping a connection open to it?

Comment: Seems to make sense it doesn't just work. You can try to tweak the system or elevate the rights of your app https://medium.com/@im-jqueue/uiaccess-and-uipi-beyond-sending-inputs-to-interfaces-db9efbd8b339 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-securityoverview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-only-elevate-uiaccess-applications-that-are-installed-in-secure-locations (untested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to make that work using [SendInput()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput). However, mouse clicks are working great using [SendMessage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage):

```cs
PInvoke.SendMessage(hwnd, PInvoke.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (nuint)MODIFIERKEYS_FLAGS.MK_LBUTTON, PInvoke.MAKELPARAM(X, Y));
PInvoke.SendMessage(hwnd, PInvoke.WM_LBUTTONUP, (nuint)MODIFIERKEYS_FLAGS.MK_LBUTTON, PInvoke.MAKELPARAM(X, Y));
```

The cool thing about SendMessage is that the clicks can be sent to minimized windows. However, this is not true for keyboard messages, they are only effective if the window is focused.